# Exponential equation with same, unknown bases

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

I have the following equation:

$(x-3)^{(x^2-x)} = (x-3)^2$

The book says solutions are: $x_1 = -1, x_2 = 2, x_3 = 3, x_4 = 4$
I was only able to get -1, 2, 4 by doing this:

$(x-3)^{(x^2-x)} = (x-3)^2 / \log$

$(x^2-x) \cdot \log(x-3) = 2\log(x-3)$ (exponents out)

$(x^2-x) \cdot \log(x-3) - 2\log(x-3) = 0$

$\log(x-3)(x^2-x - 2) = 0$

$\log(x-3) = 0 \; \lor \; x^2-x-2=0 $

$x-3=1 \; \lor \; x^2-x-2=0 $

$x_1 = 4, \; x_2 = -1, \; x_3 = 2$

The explanation in the book says only this:

$x-3 = 1 \; \lor \; (x-3 = 0 \; \land \; x^2-x \ne 0) \; \lor \; (x-3 \ne 0 \; \land \; x^2-x=2)$

What exactly am I missing here? I don't quite undersand the book's explanation though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a^m=a^n$

either $m=n$

or $a=0, mn>0$

or $a=1$

or $a=-1,m-n=$  some even integer

By taking logarithm, we implicitly assume $a\ne0$

Comment: According to the book, when m = n, then a ≠ 0 (or vice-versa?). I concluded that from the 3rd statement contained in the last row of my OP. (x−3≠0∧x^2−x=2) Is that correct?

Comment: @Pixel, Why $m=n\implies a\ne0$? The idea is if $a\ne0,\pm1, m=n$

Comment: The second to last line:  $$a=-1,m-n=even$$It won't work if $m-n$ is odd.